# What's the fastest way to migrate an Oracle database from Unix to Linux?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, migration

We have an Oracle database installed on AIX 7.1, and now we want to migrate our database instance to RedHat 6.2.

The RedHat server has Oracle 11.2 installed already.

What's the fastest way to migrate my database to our new Linux server?

I tried create a template (structure and data) on the AIX server, and then upload those template files to RedHat server, but dbca failed to create new database with this template, the error message says "bad file header".

Comment: If Oracle is already running on the RedHat server, use `expdp` and `impdp` (or just `impdp` through a DBlink)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do I need to create a database on redhat first?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name impdp seems work on schema level, not database level. I just have oracle installed on redhat, no databases created via dbca.

Comment: what means 'fastest'? shortest downtime, least preparation time?

Answer (score 1):

Is hard to say which method is faster, but I would say from my experience using source backup is faster than import.

It seems the issue you see with the file header when you use the source files comes from the file format of AIX which is big endian, while on Linux is small endian.

The files need to be converted. This can be done using RMAN:

```sh
RMAN> convert datafile 'bla' 
    TO PLATFORM="Linux 64-bit for AMD (or your platform)" 
    FROM PLATFORM="AIX-Based Systems (64-bit) - or your platform"

    (note: line breaks added for readability)
```